# Using - window.history.pushState to update the page/URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

I'm interested in having my app update w/o page refresh and without a # hash in a URL.

I've seen jQuery BBQ which uses the hash but then came github's recent blog post about pushState which looks great.

```
https://gist.github.com/730603
```

Does anyone know of any tutorials showing how to use it? Or perhaps can provide an example of how to implement this to use pushState with certain links on the web app?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen this but that isn't a security hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: (I know you mentioned GitHub but I wasn't sure if you were aware of the actual post of just the Gist)
GitHub recently blogged about it: https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider

Edit:
There's also a great RailsCasts episode on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state